# Azure Powershell Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, azure

- Are there any more cmdlets for Linux Azure Powershell apart from [these](https://www.powershellgallery.com/items?q=netcore&x=0&y=0)?
- Is there an official repository for Azure Powershell **for Linux**?
- Is there a way for terminal to launch powershell on startup, not bash?

My google-fu is weak today :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is old but I'll still answer it. In hopes that you will receive my response via email, others seeking help in the future will see this, and to establish reputation on this damn site so I can actually start using it effectively.

> - Are there any more cmdlets for Linux Azure Powershell apart from these?

I assume you're specifically looking for Azure because of your title. AzureRM.Netcore has been released as of ~1 month ago. This supports 90% of the functionality you need to deploy to Azure.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Netcore/0.9.1

Unfortunately, I am finding that some older cmdlets are not supported yet though, since they are in an older module called Azure, which does not yet have a .NET Core implementation. See [my recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697022/azure-powershell-module-linux-net-core-support/45697083#45697083) for more information on that.

> - Is there an official repository for Azure Powershell for Linux?

You can find all of that discussion on the official Powershell repository. It is cross-platform. Additionally Microsoft intends to build Powershell 6 on top of .NET Core 2.0 which was released yesterday. So it's likely that future development will heavily support Linux. This will be your best resource: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell

> - Is there a way for terminal to launch powershell on startup, not bash?

There is. But I wouldn't recommend doing that. That just sounds wrong. But I'm a pretentious Linux user with a bias towards Microsoft so take my opinion with a grain of salt. There are two methods you can use to accomplish that.

1) Most Linux distros come with a command called `chsh` just for that. Try `chsh -s /usr/bin/powershell` provide that is the location of your installed Powershell binary. If you are not sure where it is, you can use `which` to determine the installation location. `which powershell`. Do not execute this command with `sudo` as that will attempt to change the shell for your root user rather than your current user.

2) Alternatively you can manually edit the file `/etc/passwd` on Linux. Locate the line that contains your user account, go to the very end of it, and replace `/bin/bash` or whatever shell you use with `/usr/bin/powershell`, or the proper location of your Powershell Binary.

Comment: hey thanks, I forgot about this one. I'm a bit more educated on linux now, so I kinda new some of these already, but still, thanks ;) I wonder if your upvote on that answer will work now ;)