# Azure Powershell Module - Linux (.NET Core) Support

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, asp.net-core

There exists an AzureRM module that is built on .NET Core. However, the AzureRM module doesn't have all of the required functionality to interact with Azure. Many of the other cmdlets, such as `New-AzureAffinityGroup`, are present in the Azure module. Here are a list of other cmdlets: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Azure/4.2.1

When can we expect support for this module and the remaining Azure cmdlets to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Microsoft doesn't give any eta on when "classic" things are going to get fully ported into ARM.  But almost everything was already ported, so I would expect "classic" to be fully ported to ARM in a year or so.
2. AzureRM.Netcore is way behind AzureRM, and Microsoft doesn't give any eta when they will be on par, but Powershell 6 is being built on top of .Net Core, so I would expect AzureRM.Netcore match AzureRM at some point in time, but not really soon, obviously.

Meanwhile, you can work around with rest calls. That's a bit of a different talk, but easiest way to do this is perform the command you know works and add a "-Debug" to it (`New-AzureAffinityGroup -bla blabla ... -Debug`). It will print out (well, not sure about old cmdlets, but AzureRM cmdlets do that) the rest call it performed. Another way - take a look at [Azure API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I recognize that Linux Powershell must use AzureRM.Netcore. That is why I said:

"There exists an AzureRM module that is built on .NET Core." 

I apologize for my choice of phrasing.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question. 

I recognize AzureRM.Netcore exists. I have used it to create a 250+ line deployment script now. However, This module does not have all of the required functionality to interact with Azure. It is missing several key cmdlets, including `New-AzureAffinityGroup`. These cmdlets are located in another module, called `Azure`. Which is what I linked to. Not AzureRM. My question was asking when this module will have a .NET Core implementation. Your initial answer, `1)`, satisfied this question. My comment was in regards to your `2)` response.

Comment: I think I'll hold out for a few in hopes of someone on the dev team providing some insight on the progress of development. Discussion around the development of AzureRM.Netcore was relatively prominent on GitHub. 

In the event that I have to, I suppose I would consider "...in a year or so." to be the most satisfying unsatisfactory answer though.

Comment: well, its not like I can speed up powershell development ;)))

Comment: Haha I know. I was just being cheeky.

On another note, If you could find the time I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me with an example of how to deploy an Affinity Group by performing REST calls to Azure. I am more of a system engineer than a software engineer so my experience with REST APIs is quite limited. I have maybe intentionally performed 5-10 REST API calls via software that I wrote in my life.

Comment: updated, also, why do you need affinity groups, they are obsolete, aren't they? why not use ARM Compute model?

Comment: You're correct. Thank you for the perspective. I marked your reply as the answer. My upvote was recorded by SO but not displayed as they hate me because I don't have enough reputation yet. (I want to shoot myself for using Reddit instead for my tech questions these past few years. SO is very cruel to those without reputation)

Comment: its really not that hard to build it up. just keep answering peoples questions and thats it (not that there is any point in doing so after you have like 200 of it)