# Industry Standard Methods of Automating Azure Resource Deployment

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, deployment, asp.net-core

I have recently began automating the deployment of all of the Azure resources and other modifications that need to be made to build the dev environments at my company. I started working with Powershell on Linux using the .NET Core release of the AzureRM module. Come to find out, half of the cmdlets for interacting with Azure are present in another module, Azure. Which doesn't have a .NET Core release yet. See [my other recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697022/azure-powershell-module-linux-net-core-support/45697083#45697083) for additional details on that issue.

I tried running my script today on Windows and it bombed horribly. Probably due to some weird syntactical differences between the platforms or something. I haven't began troubleshooting yet. But this led me to thinking about whether or not Powershell was even the best solution. Can anyone recommend an alternative method?

Preferably something less proprietary with better cross-platform support. I recognize there are similar questions on StackOverflow. But they address entire applications and CI/CD pipelines. I'm mostly referring to the underlying resource groups, security rules, etc. However I will likely also leverage this script to deploy k8s, couchbase, etc as well. So perhaps an entire design change is in order.

I'm looking forward to your insight, friends.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their **programming code** (not verbal descriptions/discussions). Requests for philosophies, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, @shellter.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: > "Preferably something less proprietary with better cross-platform support"
PS is open source and cross platform. but if you want something more familiar in non-MS realms, check out the 'az' cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/get-started-with-azure-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using powershell on linux\windows to deploy resources to Azure without much of a hassle. But for resource provisioning I'd go with ARM Templates to automate deployments, as they can be deployed with almost anything, are kinda easy to understand when you scan through them and they are just a bunch of json.

ARM templates can be plugged into ansible (which I'm using currently) and some other things (like VSTS, Terraform, etc)

Also, `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` and `New\Get\Remove-AzureRmResource` are available on linux and windows and can be used to do pretty much anything in Azure (but they are a lot trickier than native cmdlets).

Comment: Cheers, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: you have to keep in mind this is my limited experience, you (or somebody else) might come up with something better ;)