# "New-AzureStorageContext" not recognized. Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been running a script that downloads all my BLOB files on my windows machine. I had no problem. Now i'm trying to do the same on my Ubuntu 16.10.

I've installed PowerShell on my distribution. When I try to run my script:

```
Clear-Host
$SubscriptionName = "MySubName"
$StorageAccountName = "MyStorageAccountName" 
$StorageAccountKey = "SecretKey"
$ContainerName = "MyContainerName"
$localTargetDirectory = "/home/"

#Set up the storage account context 
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $ctx

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $ctx

foreach($Blob in $blobs){
    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $Blob.Name -Container $ContainerName -Destination $localTargetDirectory -Context $ctx -Force
    }
```

PowerShell does not recognize several commands.

```
New-AzureStorageContext : The term 'New-AzureStorageContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At /home/file.ps1
```

So I tried to install AzureRM module:

```
PS /home> Install-Module AzureRM
```

It works. Now I import the Module:

```
PS /home> Import-Module AzureRM
Import-Module : The specified module 'AzureRM' was not loaded because no valid     module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ import-module <<<<  azurerm
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (azurerm:String) [Import-    Module], FileNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

How can fix this? Maybe get the module file in direct download and put it in module directory?

EDIT:
I tried to download manually `AzureRM` module (version 4.3.1) like this:

```
PS /home> Save-Module -Name AzureRM -Path ~/.local/share/powershell/modules/ -RequiredVersion 4.3.1
PS /home> Install-Module -Name AzureRM
```

Modules did download, installation gives no out-put and still doesn't work.

EDIT:

I've found an other tool that don't use PowerShell.
[AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json&view=azuremobileserverentity-2.0.0)

Comment: Hi, your storage account is classic mode storage account? Now, classic Azure PowerShell cmdlet is not supported on Linux.

Comment: I don't find the classic notation. I guess it is a new storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697022/azure-powershell-module-linux-net-core-support/45697083#45697083) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666129/azure-powershell-linux).

> Unfortunately, I am finding that some older cmdlets are not supported
>   yet though, since they are in an older module called Azure, which does
>   not yet have a .NET Core implementation.

Now, [AzureRM.Netcore](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Netcore/0.9.1) is supported on Linux PowerShell.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Netcore
```

Currently, it only supports ARM cmdlets.  Unfortunately, `New-AzureStorageContext` does not be supported.

If you use ARM storage account, you could install [`AzureRM.Storage.Netcore`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Storage.Netcore/0.9.1).

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey New-AzureRmStorageAccount New-AzureRmStorageAccountKey Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount Set-AzureRmStorageAccount Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability Get-AzureRmStorageUsage
```

These cmdlets are supported on Linux Powershell.

Update:

Now, Azcopy is supported on Linux, you could use Azcopy to transfer files or directory, please refer to this [link:Transfer data with AzCopy on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json&view=azuremobileserverentity-2.0.0).

Comment: I don't know if I can do the same task (downloading my blob files) with `AzureRM.Storage.Netcore` I have to read more the documentation.

Comment: If your storage account is arm mode, you could use `$storKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -Name $storAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName ).Key1`.

Comment: @BeGreen Thanks for your share, Azcopy could work on Linux, I add it to my answer. Power Shell on Linux is not support Azure classic cmdlets. Azcopy is a good choice.

Comment: @BeGreen I test on my knowledge, for your scenario, powershell on linux could not support.